# How to aggretage col1 per ID and val1 per ID and values in col1 in SAS Enterprise Gude or PROC SQL?

Tags: sas, aggregate, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

```
ID  | COL1 | VAL1 |  
----|------|------|
111 | A    | 10   | 
111 | A    | 5    | 
111 | B    | 10   | 
222 | B    | 20   |
333 | C    | 25   |
... | ...  | ...  |
```

And I need to aggregate above table to know:

- sum of values from COL1 per ID
- sum of values from VAL1 per COL1 per ID

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
ID  | COL1_A | COL1_B | COL1_C  | COL1_A_VAL1_SUM | COL1_B_VAL1_SUM | COL1_C_VAL1_SUM
----|--------|--------|---------|-----------------|-----------------|------------------
111 | 2      | 1      | 0       | 15              | 10              | 0
222 | 0      | 1      | 0       | 0               | 20              | 0
333 | 0      | 0      | 1       | 0               | 0               | 25
```

for example because:

- COL1_A = 2 for ID 111, because ID=111 has 2 times "A" in COL1
- COL1_A_VAL1_SUM = 15 for ID 111, because ID=111 has 10+5=15 in VAL1 for "A" in COL1

How can I do that in SAS Enterpriuse Guide or in PROC SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we'll create the counts that we need by group with SQL:

```
proc sql;
    create table totals_by_group as
        select id
             , col1
             , count(col1) as count_col1
             , sum(val1)   as sum_val1
        from have
        group by id, col1
    ;
quit;
```

This produces the following table:

```
id  col1    count_col1  sum_val1
111 A       2           15
111 B       1           10
222 B       1           20
333 C       1           25
```

Now we need to transpose this into the way we want it. We'll do this with two transpose steps: one for `count_col1`, and one for `sum_val1`. `proc transpose` has a few handy options to make this easy, namely the `id`, `prefix`, and `suffix` options.

First, we'll consider our ID variable `col1`. This creates columns named `A`, `B`, and `C`. For example:

```
id  A   B   C
111 2   1   .
222 .   1   .
333 .   .   1
```

The `prefix` and `suffix` options let us add a prefix and suffix to these names.

```
proc transpose 
    data   = totals_by_group 
    out    = count_by_group(drop=_NAME_)
    prefix = COL1_;

    by id;
    id col1;
    var count_col1;
run;

proc transpose 
    data   = totals_by_group 
    out    = sum_by_group(drop=_NAME_)
    prefix = COL1_ 
    suffix = _VAL1_SUM;

    by id;
    id col1;
    var sum_val1;
run;
```

This gives us two tables:

```
COUNT_BY_GROUP 
id  COL1_A  COL1_B  COL1_C
111 2       1       .
222 .       1       .
333 .       .       1

SUM_BY_GROUP
id  COL1_A_VAL1_SUM COL1_B_VAL1_SUM COL1_C_VAL1_SUM
111 15              10              .
222 .               20              .
333 .               .               25
```

Now we just need to merge them together, then set all missing values to 0 by iterating over each numeric column and checking if it's missing.

```
data want;
    merge count_by_group  
          sum_by_group
    ;
    by id;

    array numvars[*] _NUMERIC_;

    do i = 1 to dim(numvars);
        if(missing(numvars[i])) then numvars[i] = 0;
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

Final table:

```
id  COL1_A  COL1_B  COL1_C  COL1_A_VAL1_SUM COL1_B_VAL1_SUM COL1_C_VAL1_SUM
111 2       1       0       15              10              0
222 0       1       0       0               20              0
333 0       0       1       0               0               25
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you Stu Sztukowski, I gave best answer! :)